# 'DynamicTransform' could not be found while generating a CustomScaffolder by T4Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, t4scaffolding

I am trying to use T4Scaffolding for my current project but it fails at the beginning.

I do step by step same process on [this link](http://average-uffe.blogspot.com/2011/06/basics-in-t4scaffolding-in-visual.html) that teaches how to use T4Scaffolding for a basic console application.

**Steps that I did**

**1-** I created a new console application (.NET 4.0)

**2-** I installed T4Scaffholding successfully by using package manager console (install-package t4scaffolding)

**3-** I tried to create a demo custom template by using package manager console like

*`Scaffold CustomScaffolder T4Demo`*

then it throws the exception below

```
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate : c:\Users\ryu\Desktop\SpiderWeb\ConsoleApplication2\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\CustomScaffolder\DefaultPs1Script.ps1.t4(1,48) : error CS0246: Com
piling transformation: The type or namespace name 'DynamicTransform' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
At C:\Users\ryu\Desktop\SpiderWeb\ConsoleApplication2\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\CustomScaffolder\T4Scaffolding.CustomScaffolder.ps1:15 char:1
+ Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template DefaultPs1Script -Model @{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.AddProjectItemViaTemplateCmdlet

Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate : c:\Users\ryu\Desktop\SpiderWeb\ConsoleApplication2\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\CustomScaffolder\DefaultT4Template.cs.t4(1,48) : error CS0246: Com
piling transformation: The type or namespace name 'DynamicTransform' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
At C:\Users\ryu\Desktop\SpiderWeb\ConsoleApplication2\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\CustomScaffolder\T4Scaffolding.CustomScaffolder.ps1:22 char:1
+ Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template DefaultT4Template -Model @{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.AddProjectItemViaTemplateCmdlet
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I changed my windows regional setting from my native language to USA, the problem has gone. Do not forget to restart Visual Studio.

really annoying problem !